# Pronunciation of words ending with “-tion”

Tags: pronunciation, suffixes, sibilants

As far as I can recall there are just a few words in the English language which end with the spelling *-tion* after an 'S' which have a pronunciation ending as 'chan'. But in South Asia, 99% of the people pronounce such words as 'shan'.

I am referring to words like *digestion*, *suggestion*, *combustion*, *congestion*, *indigestion*, *exhaustion*, etc.

But people pronounce the word *question* correctly as 'chan'.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum; invitations to comment are explicitly discouraged in the [help]. I would also advise you to take the site [tour] for a better understanding of how our site operates.

Answer (score 1):

The correct pronunciation of all the words mentioned above ends with **'chan'**.

Since 'English' is not the native language of South Asians, their pronunciation may have some flaws. However, many South Asians are picking up correct pronunciation with more global exposure.

Comment: How can this post answer the question? How do you pronounce **chan**?